# Changing default Bootstrap carousel slide animation direction?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Is there a way to make a reversed bootstrap carousel slide animation? I dont want to change

```
1 2 3 4
```

to

```
4 3 2 1
```

I just want to make it appear in reverse order, is that possible?

Code looks something like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <div class="kampany">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="kampanyapic px-0">
                        <div id="kampanyacontrol" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                              <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517994112540-009c47ea476b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="First slide">
                              </div>
                              <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494905998402-395d579af36f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="Second slide">
                              </div>
                              <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503736334956-4c8f8e92946d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="Third slide">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#kampanyacontrol" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                            
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="kampanyainfo px-0">
                        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                                          <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517994112540-009c47ea476b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="First slide">
                              </div>
                              <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494905998402-395d579af36f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="Second slide">
                              </div>
                              <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503736334956-4c8f8e92946d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="Third slide">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   <script>
 $('.kampany .carousel-control-next,.kampany .carousel-control-prev').on('click', function (e) {
          var inst = $(this).data("slide");
          if(inst== "prev"){ 
          $("#carouselExampleControls").carousel("prev")}
          else{ $("#kampanyacontrol").carousel("next")}
        })
</script>
```

So here I just want to make the right carousel slite mirrored respectively to left carousel. I dont want to change directions on either of them if thats possible. So at the end both of them will slide in to the same image synchronized.

Comment: the slide u provide its actually tow slides the left slide start an then the right slide start, 
 all your js file is from cdn so I think you can't adjust them only if you imported to your project , the best solution is to make one slide and put the company image on the right and the company info to the left and make some margin on them it will show exactly the slide you provide

Comment: I understand. Well I actally want the splitting efect. Withouth default slide directions changed, i don't think i can make it work.

Comment: in that case you can delay the second slide ( not recommended )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out!

```js
$('.carousel-sync').carousel('cycle');
$('.carousel-sync').on('click', '.carousel-control-next[data-slide]', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('.carousel-sync').carousel($(this).data('slide'));
});
$('.carousel-sync').on('click', '.carousel-control-prev[data-slide]', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('.carousel-sync').carousel($(this).data('slide'));
});


$('.carousel-sync').on('mouseover', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('.carousel-sync').carousel('pause');
});
$('.carousel-sync').on('mouseleave', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('.carousel-sync').carousel('cycle');
});
```

```css
.kampanyainfo .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
.kampanyainfo .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.kampanyainfo .carousel-item-next,
.kampanyainfo .active.carousel-item-right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

.kampanyainfo .carousel-item-prev,
.kampanyainfo .active.carousel-item-left {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}


.kampanyapic .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
.kampanyapic .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.kampanyapic .carousel-item-next,
.kampanyapic .active.carousel-item-right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}

.kampanyapic .carousel-item-prev,
.kampanyapic .active.carousel-item-left {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <div class="kampany">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="kampanyapic px-0">
                        <div id="kampanyacontrol" class="carousel carousel-sync slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                              <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517994112540-009c47ea476b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="First slide">
                              </div>
                              <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494905998402-395d579af36f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="Second slide">
                              </div>
                              <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503736334956-4c8f8e92946d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="Third slide">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#kampanyacontrol" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                            
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="kampanyainfo px-0">
                        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel carousel-sync slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                                          <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517994112540-009c47ea476b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="First slide">
                              </div>
                              <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494905998402-395d579af36f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="Second slide">
                              </div>
                              <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503736334956-4c8f8e92946d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="Third slide">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This worked for me!